# iterm2 - how do I get the current working directory to display on the left of each line?

Tags: unix, iterm2

I've just installed iterm2 and found that it doesn't show the current working directory (i.e folder you are in) on each line. I thought iterm2 did this by default as it did this when I previously worked with it. Please see screenshot of what I am talking about.
How do I configure it do it will display the working directory? (as per the screenshot).
Thanks in advance!

[each line should ideally display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z72wP.png)

I have tried going into the settings of iterm2, and also attempted to edit the bash_profile (couldn't find it).

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the iTerm2 terminal emulator. You appear to be asking how to modify the Bash prompt to include the CWD. Which is a FAQ. If you search for phrases such as "configure bash prompt to include CWD" you'll find plenty of answers.

Comment: Also, you say you "attempted to edit the bash_profile" but don't tell us the actual filename you attempted to edit or what you intended to put in the file. So we have no idea what you attempted to do. FYI, the Bash config file relevant for interactive shells is *~/.bashrc*.

Comment: Thanks. Less criticism more helping please. As per the msg below - I am new to this - please be kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this google search: ["configure bash prompt to include CWD"](https://www.google.com/search?q=configure+bash+prompt+to+include+CWD&oq=configure+bash+prompt+to+include+CWD&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggAEEUYOzIGCAAQRRg70gEHODc0ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). It resulted in many answers, such as this [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/601181/how-to-display-current-path-in-command-prompt-in-linuxs-sh-not-bash) question. There is more than one way to do this but perhaps the simplest, and most performant, is something along these lines:

```
PS1='\w> '
```

This is what happens on my system (which has an ancient version of Bash):

```
bash> PS1='\w> '
~> cd /tmp
/tmp> cd /var/log
/var/log> cd /usr/local
/usr/local>
```

You can obviously include anything else you want in the prompt. See the section in `man bash` titled "PROMPTING" which lists the magic escape sequences you can include in the `PS1` variable.